# Using flash (or something similar) to display video preview for video collage

Tags: flash

I run a website that allows users to create video collages. I want users to be able to preview their collages before they submit their videos for processing. I've already tried displaying multiple `<video>` elements; this is very slow and the timing for the previews is always off. Is there a way I can use flash (or a similar technology) to create video previews of video collages before processing (which takes minutes -- allowing users to preview their collages allows users to subclip their clips (another feature on the site) to have the desired timing for their clips). Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using HTML5 canvas to render the video previews? I'm unaware if it's possible to seek to a certain time on video sources nor if it is possible to render a certain frame at a certain time, but I believe it's worth a try.

Comment: I looked into that, the audio does not render, apparently. The audio needs to be rendered together with the video